# Apps Script Gadget on Google Site started throwing CORS errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, cors, google-sites

I have a Google Site with multiple pages all containing a Google Apps Script Gadget. Users have reported that a couple of months ago, the Apps Script Gadgets stopped working. I have tested them, and found that the Apps Script gadget loads correctly and displays content from UI service, however, when any button is clicked that runs a function, the Apps Script Gadget hangs and a console error in the browser shows:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'frame' property from 'Window': Blocked a frame                      
with origin "https://sites.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin
"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-a-sites-opensocial.googleusercontent.com".
Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Have Google changed some kind of security policy that prevents Cross Origin requests from being made to Apps Script  Scripts? Is there any kind of workaround for this?

Thanks

Stu

Comment: Provide more info. Exactly how have you inserted the script into the site? By url? Does the url begin with 'script' or 'sites'.

Comment: The script is inserted into the site using a Google Apps Script Gadget. The Url begins with script.google.com

Comment: I would try using a link that opened the Apps Script Gadget in another tab as a work around.  `<a href="https://URL to Your deployed AppsScript.com" target="_blank">My Gadget Name</a>`

Comment: I'd be happy to look at this a bit more (I recently worked with Google Gadgets in a project) if you could provide your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could find to this issue was to replace the gadget with a link that opens the Apps Script URL in a new page.